# Retrieving string between whitespace

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, whitespace

I have a string which belongs to the variable tbody as shown below:

```
tbody = 
'...
</td>
<td class="Details clearfix">
<div>
<b>

9. I want this text and number

            </b>
</div>
</td>
<td class="flux">
...'

>print type(tbody)
<type 'str'>
```

As you might have already seen there is whitespace.
I have tried to retrieve '9. I want this text and number' using the following code:

```
tbody2 = str(tbody.split(','))
tbody2 = str(re.split('\n|\r|\t', tbody2))
m = re.findall(re.compile("\\\\n(.+?)\\\\"), tbody2)
print m
```

This is the result I get:

```
[...'<td class="Details clearfix">', '<div>', '<b>',
'\\', '9. I want this text and number', '\\', '                </b>', '</div>',
'</td>', '<td class="flux>'...]
```

I couldn't get the string so is there a way of retrieving it perhaps using BS or regex? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tbody = """
<td class="Details clearfix">
<div>
<b>

9. I want this text and number

            </b>
</div>
</td>

"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(tbody)
for item in soup.find_all('td',class_="Details clearfix"):
    print item.div.b.text.strip()

#output= 9. I want this text and number
```

i think there is no need of splitting you fetch the expected output by search in beautiful soup

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through Python's re module using DOTALL modifier,

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'<td.*?>.*?<b>\s*([^\n]*).*<\/b>.*?<\/td>', tbody, re.DOTALL)
>>> m.group(1)
'9. I want this text and number'
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/vM8vQ5/2)